# XPATH Concatenation of two or many subclass

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping

I need to scrap datas on a website.

For example, www.example.com

The code display :

```html
<div class="first test">
  <div class="first test2">
    <ul>
      <li class="datas">One One</li>
      <li class="datas1">One Two</li>
      <li class="datas2">One Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second test">
  <div class="second test2">
    <ul>
      <li class="datas">Two One</li>
      <li class="datas1">Two Two</li>
      <li class="datas2">Two Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the text "One One", when i set

> .//*[@class='first test' and @class='first test2' and @class='datas'] it's doesn't works!

Why? please.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath doesn't work because you have just one [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) (`[ ]`) on a single element (selected with `*`).

Try something like this instead...

```
//div[@class='first test']/div[@class='first test2']/ul/li[@class='datas']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because each class pertences to different elements. Try something like that:

```
//div[@class='first test2']//li[@class='datas']
```

The code above should resolves for now but you'll have a new issue if someone add a new `li` element with "datas" class. If so you must add one more specification:

```
//div[@class='first test2']//li[@class='datas'][text()='one one']
```

This XPath works in both scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these below mentioned `xpath` to locate the webelement `One One`

To get the webelement using `preceding keyword`

```
//div[@class='second test']/..//preceding::div[@class='first test2']//li[text()='One One']
```

> OR

To get the webelement using `following-sibling keyword`

```
//div[@class='first test2']/..//following-sibling::li[text()='One One']
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's work for you.